# Sending MKShape to paramter of incompatible type id MKOverlay Nonnull

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkoverlay, mkpolygon

I am receiving this warning while I am overlaying the geometry on the map.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Warning: "Sending MKShape to paramter of incompatible type id MKOverlay Nonnull."

[image]

```
@interface store : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) MKShape *storeGeometry;

// On map   
 if([store.storeGeometry isKindOfClass:MKPolygon.class]) {
                [self.map addOverlay:store.storeGeometry];
            }
```

Comment: similar kind of question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234808/how-to-get-apple-maps-app-not-mapkit-to-add-an-annotation/43243556#43243556

Comment: @Fattie In the link that you have provided discusses more about `MKAnnotations`. My question is related to `MKOverlay`